# Passing a variable inside a UIAlertController textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, uialertcontroller

I am having difficulty with assigning a variable with the text that is written in the textfield inside a UIAlertViewController. The userPassword seems to be coming up as nil even after the block execution. Here is the relevant code.

```
__block NSString *userPassword = nil;



[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.placeholder = @"Password";
    textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    userPassword=textField.text;

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:` is for adding text fields to the `UIAlertController` and its block is executed before the user sees the alert and long before the user has the opportunity to type in the text fields. When you add actions to the alert, `addAction:`, thats where you can access the text fields for user-provided information.

```
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title 
                                          style:style 
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // loop is for example, replace to suit your needs
    // probably with something like
    // [alert.textFields objectAtIndex:pwIndex].text ...
    for (UITextField *textField in alert.textFields) {
        if (textField.secureTextEntry) {
            self.userPassword = textField.text;

            // do something with the password.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see all of your code, in this case it would probably be better at the top of the class to declare a public property,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userPassword;
```

Then assign it like...

```
self.userPassword = textField.text;
```